# How to use backslash with sed?

Tags: sed

I'm trying to insert some word to text file by sed.

Problem is that some word have the following string

```
 -sv /
```

so I want to find `-sv /` then insert `-ALLOWTEXT /` below `-sv /`.

so I used

```
find . -name "main.v" -exec sed -i '/-sv //a -ALLOWTEXT \\n' "{}" \;
```

and I got error as below

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unknown command: `/'
```

EDIT:  Sorry my typo.
-sv / should be    -sv \

I want to find `-sv \` then insert `-ALLOWTEXT \` below `-sv \`.
so I run

```
  find . -name "main.v" -exec  sed -i '/-sv \//a -ALLOWTEXT \//' {} \;
```

by refering a great answer.

then it works. ;)

Comment: Firstly, those aren't backslashes (\\), those are slashes (/). (:

Comment: Please update the text of your question. Now some of the text say you used `-sv /` (including the bit with the error message from `sed`) while other parts of it say you used ``-sv \``.  The question needs to be clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given file containing the text:

```
-sv /
```

To insert below that a line containing the following text:

```
 -ALLOWTEXT /
```

with GNU `sed`:

```
$ cat input.txt
-sv /
$ sed '/-sv \//a -ALLOWTEXT /' input.txt
-sv /
-ALLOWTEXT /
```

---

Because `/`s are special characters to `sed`, when they're in the text you want to look for, you need to escape them with a preceding `\`.

Comment: You don't need the last backslash —  slash is not special in an **```a```** command.

Comment: You could use almost any character: `\,-sv /,a -ALLOWTEXT /`

Comment: Thanks so much but      -sv / is my typo.      -sv / should be      -sv \

Comment: Because backslashes are the escape character, the way to output a literal backslash is to put two of them in series (\\\).